# Как в Atom заставить разворачиваться конструкцию emmet-а "div.class" по табуляции в php файлах?

Tags: php, html, atom, emmet

Дело в том, что в html файлах отрабатывает: `div.some-class` преобразовывается в 
`<div class="some-class"></div>` при нажатии табуляции, когда курсор стоит в конце конструкции, а в php файлах такая система не работает. Как заставить это работать в **php** файлах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конфигурации горячих клавиш Emmet по умолчанию про <kbd>Tab</kbd> написано следующее:

```coffee
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html basic"]:not([mini]), atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="erb"]:not([mini]), atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="jade"]:not([mini]), atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="css"]:not([mini]), atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="stylus"]:not([mini]), atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="sass"]:not([mini]), atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="scss"]:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

*(Этот селектор пугает ровно до того момента, пока не начнёте смотреть его по секциям, разделённым запятыми: после этого он сразу приобретает смысл)*

Чтобы получить этот кусок конфигурации, откройте настройки, *Keybindings*, наберите в поиске `expand-abbreviation` и нажмите кнопку [image: введите сюда описание изображения] напротив `tab`. Соответствующий кусок конфигурации будет скопирован в буфер обмена.

Формат основан на [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson): как JSON, но с ароматом *CoffeeScript*.

В этом же окне наверху есть ссылка *your keymap file*. Нажав на неё, вы попадёте в файл конфигурации собственных горячих клавиш. Вставьте туда скопированный кусочек.

Как видно, он имеет формат:

```coffee
'селектор':
  'кнопка': 'команда'
```

Чтобы указать его действие в PHP-файлах, нужно написать соответствующий селектор. Следуя примерам из настроек по умолчанию, например, такой:

```coffee
atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html php"]:not([mini])
```

*(Применимость селекторов можно проверить, открыв DevTools и найдя в DOM узел с редактором, в котором вы хотите, чтобы горячая клавиша действовала. Посмотрите на селектор, на узел, и попробуйте выполнить сопоставление в уме.)*

Получится что-то такое:

```coffee
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html php"]:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Сохраняйте, пробуйте.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло.

Comment: @Follower вместо таких реплик у нас принято оставлять на ответе галочку. Спасибо!

Comment: Пардон, еще не со всем интерфейсом знаком)

Comment: @Follower пройдите [tour].